# What is a good (legal) form of self defense in China

Tags: safety, china, beijing

Going to China next week, and have been reading a lot of stuff on bringing pepper spray, it seems like it is illegal, but you would probably only get into trouble if you actually used it. But if I'm using it, I don't think I would have any issue dealing with the repercussions

So is pepper spray a good option to bring, or are there alternatives that are just as effective as a self defense mechanism, that you wouldn't get in trouble for using?

Yes - I understand that China is a "Fairly Safe" place. However, I would still like to know what my options are.

Comment: What are you up to that you see such a need for self defense? China is a [fairly safe place](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/china/safety-and-security).

Comment: @mts standard tourist stuff like great wall etc. But I mean, my hometown is a fairly safe place as well, doesn't mean that I don't walk around with some form of self defense.

Comment: @Adjit: My hometown is a fairly safe place, as well, and it means that I do not remotely consider any need for carrying any means of self-defense. Maybe your place is not at all as "fairly safe" as you seem to believe?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper New York, US, is a pretty safe place. And I'm not carrying around anything that is hindering my agility. The question was not `do you think I need self defense`, it is what can be used as a legal form of self defense.

Comment: Beijing is much more orderly than New York, particularly in the central tourist areas, where there are a lot of soldiers and plain clothes police. It is very unlikely you would need to defend yourself. Also you can expect to be regularly searched for weapons if you go into tourist places like museums or Tiananmen Square, and even at metro stations.

Comment: I suspect that New York is less safe (from a violent crime perspective) than Beijing. Certainly the homicide rate in China as a whole is lower than that for the US (although I don't know how comparable those statistics are).

Comment: @Calchas "Beijing is much more orderly than New York, you'll be surrounded by soliders and police officers everywhere you go!  They'll even search you whenever you walk through town!".  Sounds wonderful.

Comment: About to be censored: http://www.alibaba.com/products/F0/self_defense/CID3019.html?spm=a2700.7724838.12.2.pgFKEI

Comment: @easymoden00b It's an authoritarian communist state. What did you expect? ;)

Comment: @Calchas an egalitarian utopia were the Worker has full control of the means of production.

Comment: I suggest you master several different forms of martial arts and study old gong fu films such as *Fist of Fury*.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Some people prefer to have the means to defend themselves because the cost of being completely unable to defend oneself in a dangerous situation can be very high (i.e., as high as your *life* or the lives of those you love). Even if the probability of falling into a dangerous situation through no fault of your own is low, it is not unreasonable to wish to mitigate the risk as much as possible. It is, however, unreasonable to badger people for wanting to do so.

Comment: @jpmc26: Exactly because it is reasonable to wish to mitigate the risk to one's life or the lives of those you love, it is also absolutely reasonable to question whether those who consider increasing that risk by carrying around dangerous objects know what they are doing. They may be having valid reasons and a valid background to handle the respective objects, but it's better to ask beforehand than to be sorry afterwards.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Look, here's the point. This isn't the place to belittle people who don't agree with your political views about self defense. The question is valid and useful, and not everyone everywhere needs some kind of special qualification to have access to means to protect themselves. So it's really none of your business what background the person has or not. Is it the business of the country they're going to? If they have laws about it, sure, but all you're doing is suggesting that it's somehow wrong for people to want to have a viable means of self defense as an ordinary matter.

Comment: Get a knife and a heavy walking stick http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36094/knife-carrying-laws-in-china

Comment: @jpmc26: Questioning the premise of questions is commonplace all over the Stack Exchange network. It has nothing to do with belittling anyone, nor with promoting any particular political view, nor is it an unwarranted intrusion into anyone's business to request clarification about the motivation behind a question (for instance, to rule out an [x-y-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)), especially if the question is about behaviour that can pose a danger to the asker and others.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper This is not an example of frame challenging or an XY-problem. The OP desires some form of personal protection when visiting an unfamiliar place. (They notably ask about the comparatively mild pepper spray, not an automatic rifle.) This is a *normal* occurrence with a clear and obvious reasoning, whether you agree with it or not. This is not the kind of, "Your question doesn't make sense in this context," situation that prompts us to ask, "What are you trying to do?" Since none of that applies, your explanation doesn't make sense.

Comment: @jpmc26: 'This is not the kind of, "Your question doesn't make sense in this context," situation' - whether you agree with it or not, neither does it seem like a "normal occurrence" nor does it make much sense to me - and others who commented here - to desire personal protection for the sole reason of "visiting an unfamiliar place". You'll have to accept that not everyone shares your personal opinion. 'that prompts us to ask, "What are you trying to do?"' - it prompted mts to [ask exactly that above](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76385#comment167180_76385).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I do accept that there's disagreement about how much private citizens should protect themselves. You're the one who is implying that it's absurd that anyone would want to as part of a normal routine. The only thing I'm calling absurd is refusing to recognize the opposing viewpoint, the one held by those who believe strongly in personal protection. And since this isn't the place to debate the point, it's also not proper for you to dismiss the opposing viewpoint.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43946/discussion-on-question-by-adjit-what-is-a-good-legal-form-of-self-defense-in-c).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Pepper Spray is forbidden and likely will be discovered

[Pepper spray is forbidden in China.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper_spray#Asia) Your luggage will be searched and/or x-rayed frequently when in China, including customs controls when exiting into the airport and entering the subway or train/bus stations. There is a high chance that it will be discovered. (I've had a can of deo spray taken away when getting on a bus once. Even pocket knives get confiscated there at times.) If that happens in the best case it will be thrown away and in the worst case police will treat you as a potential terrorist. You do not want this kind of interaction with security forces.

### Right to carry arms / alternative weapons

You asked for alternative means of self-defense and mentioned in [a comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76385/what-is-a-good-legal-form-of-self-defense-in-china#comment167181_76385) that you do walk around with a form of self-defense even at home. I somehow come to assume you are a US citizen, where there is a constitutional [right to bear arms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_keep_and_bear_arms). Many Americans find it surprising that [this is not at all the case around the globe](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/53139/32134), and the principle adhered to is rather the **"[monopoly on violence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monopoly_on_violence)"** owned by the state. Carrying weapons (and be it only for self-defense) in China is highly unusual and links you to crime in the eyes of the police and public. I strongly advise against it.

It has additionally been pointed out by @Berwyn that [if shit hits the fan](http://lawprofessors.typepad.com/china_law_prof_blog/2009/04/homicide-and-selfdefense-in-china.html),

> Chinese legal culture is much less permissive in self-defense claims

compared to e.g. the US.

### Staying safe

As mentioned in [an earlier comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76385/what-is-a-good-legal-form-of-self-defense-in-china#comment167180_76385), [China is a fairly safe place](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/china/safety-and-security). If you want to be extra safe, adhere to official travel warnings of your embassy/government, e.g. the [Australian Smarttraveller.gov.au on China](http://smartraveller.gov.au/Countries/asia/north/pages/china.aspx#safety_and_security), and [the "stay safe" section on Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/China#Stay_safe).

**Your best self-defense is to avoid situations where you would need self-defense.**
That includes, but is not limited to

- don't get wasted, even better, don't get drunk
- don't do drugs - they are illegal anyway
- avoid prostitutes or any other illegal activity
- know and avoid the [scams](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Common_scams). That includes the unofficial taxis
- avoid being alone in an area. That one is easy in China
- be wary of strangers, especially those speaking (good) English
- avoid nightclubs and bars. Intoxicated folks can get aggressive (pretty much anywhere in the world)

Finally to answer your true question, if you do still feel the urge for a form of self-defense, martial arts are perfectly legal to my knowledge.

Comment: I'm surprised to see this answer accepted - while it's helpful, it doesn't answer the core question. It states that pepper spray and firearms are banned, but what methods are permitted?

Comment: @CMaster that is actually a fair point. Everyone was making a big deal about wanting a form of self defense, so I figured this was the most I'd get out of people

Comment: @CMaster "Carrying weapons (and be it only for self-defense) in China is highly unusual and links you to crime in the eyes of the police and public." implies that I advise against carrying anything. And tbh I'm surprised myself. Also note that weapons here intends not only firearms but also knives and I don't know what else.

Comment: @CMaster: The permitted methods of self-defence are quite famous around the world and are usually incorrectly known as "kung fu". One of the few instances of something approaching "racism" among the various ethnicities of China that I've heard was a stereotype that Tibetans carry knives and the same for another group I can't recall. It gave me the impression that "typical law abiding Chinese" regard carrying anything weaponish with revulsion. My impression after several visits to China is stay away from shady activities and you are very unlikely to come across shady people.

Comment: Are you actually searched yourself? In the metro I've only had my bag x-rayed and nobody wanted to check my pockets

Comment: @Berwyn I've had bags x-rayed and/or hand-searched but never had my pockets or a jacket searched.

Comment: The only time I've undergone anything remotely like being searched in Chinese is when entering the security perimeter around Tiananmen Square. I did use the metro in at least three cities in China, but not extensively.

Comment: @CMaster The answer seems pretty clear to me as to what's the best method of self defense: Common sense. Not particularly limited to China though. Or another point of view: Weapons are dangerous not just to others, but also to yourself. They also escalate situations, which is exactly the opposite of what you want in a dangerous situation.

Comment: From personal experience, I disagree that pepper spray is "likely to be discovered" in China. "Avoid being alone in an area. That one is easy in China" is also very questionable. Likely true in big cities, not so much if you're going somewhere rural.

Comment: @Voo Yes. Common sense, of course a necessity. Also, as far as escalation goes, while I agree with that statement and it is, for the most part, true in the US, as someone who is non-confrontational it is strictly for self-defense - not to be confused with trying to diffuse a situation with intimidation. I am a firm believer in plan for the worst - hope for the best.

Comment: Most knives and all clubs are allowed

Comment: @user987234 do you have any reference for that? Allowed to own or carry in public? If you do, this might be worth making it an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to carry something then you need to be creative. You could carry one of the tactical pens out there . Smith and Wesson has a pen for $30 which is made of6076 T6 aircraft aluminum. There is a screw on cap with a pointed end (but not sharpened so it is hard to think of as “a weapon”) I f you want to go cheaper get a G2 pen which goes for about a dollar. A navy this is what a Nave interagator carried at Guantanamo Bay.
Since it has a legitimate purpose then no one will take it away.
I was reading on leathermans web and they had a list of multi-tools that are legal.
Asia has a long history of unconventional weapons. For example a Tom fa (sp) which is a club with a handle on the side was actually used fir harvesting grain.

Comment: Can you take those on an airplane carry-on? Seems dubious.