# Can you have an extendable baton in China?

Tags: international-travel, legal, china, safety

I'm planning on buying an extendable baton for self defense (most likely never going to have to use it). I'm just curious if I'm allowed to have one in China since in the United States it's allowed. I couldn't really find any information on the web so I thought I would ask here.

Comment: A lot of things allowed in the states are not allowed elsewhere. Generally "it's ok in place X" has very little bearing on its legality in some other unrelated location.

Comment: Relevant: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/76385/what-is-a-good-legal-form-of-self-defense-in-china

Comment: I have edited to replace "states" by "United States".  Please [edit] your question if this is not what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/asia-pacific/mainland-chinese-music-student-among-first-to-be-sentenced-for-hong-kong-protests/2019/11/07/2b935622-013b-11ea-8341-cc3dce52e7de_story.html), expandable batons are legal in China mainland and illegal to carry in the streets in Hong Kong.

> in the states it's allowed.

That's incorrect. See this [blogpost](https://www.thehomesecuritysuperstore.com/blogs/the-home-security-superstore-blog/using-a-baton-for-self-defense-what-you-need-to-know#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20you%20can%20legally%20carry,carry%20outside%2C%20open%20or%20concealed.):

> California is the only state where expandable batons are illegal to both own and carry. In Massachusetts, New York, and Washington D.C. batons are legal to own at home but illegal to carry outside, open or concealed.

Also [mostly illegal](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F33658) to carry in France.

Comment: They are legal to buy (or at least the Chinese authorities don't care that much about it). But carrying it without obvious reasonable excuses would definitely attract police attention that you may not want.